# Show $f(t)=\frac{\Phi(\frac{-1}{s\sqrt{t}})}{(st+1)^{3/2}}$ has only 1 turning point

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory

I need to prove that $f(t)=\frac{\Phi(\frac{-1}{s\sqrt{t}})}{(st+1)^{3/2}}$ has only 1 turning point, where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal cdf, $t\geq0$, $s>0$. I have already shown that $f'(t)$ is first $\geq0$, then finally $\leq0$. But I can't show that $f'(t)=0$ only once.

Comment: what is $$\Phi'(\frac{-1}{s\sqrt{t}})$$ ?

Comment: since $\Phi$ is the normal cdf, $\Phi'(\frac{-1}{s\sqrt{t}})$ is $\phi(\frac{-1}{s\sqrt{t}})\frac{1}{2st^{3/2}}$